# R How to compute a unique index for two character variables with varing columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm not sure if I phrased my question properly, so let me give an simplified example:

Given a dataset as follows:

```
dat <- data_frame(X = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "A"), 
                  Y = c("B", "A", "C", "A", "C"))
```

how can I compute a `pair` variable, so that it represents whatever was within `X` and `Y` at a given row **BUT** not generating duplicates, as here:

```
dat$pair <- c("A-B", "A-B", "B-C", "C-A", "C-A")
dat
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  X     Y     pair 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     B     A-B  
2 B     A     A-B  
3 B     C     B-C  
4 C     A     C-A  
5 A     C     C-A
```

I can compute a pairing with paste0 but it will indroduce duplicates (`C-A` is the same as `A-C` for me) that I want to avoid:

```
> dat <- mutate(dat, pair = paste0(X, "-", Y))
> dat
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  X     Y     pair 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     B     A-B  
2 B     A     B-A  
3 B     C     B-C  
4 C     A     C-A  
5 A     C     A-C
```

Comment: Does your data only include upper case letters and one letter in each element?

Comment: @blazej Does the order matter? For example, would `A-C` and `A-C` be acceptable instead of `C-A` and `C-A`?

Comment: @Peter, no - its actually longer strigs with multiple chatacters

Comment: @Ben yes, thats just fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `pmin` and `pmax` to sort the values parallely and `paste` them.

```
transform(dat, pair = paste(pmin(X, Y), pmax(X, Y), sep = '-'))

#  X Y pair
#1 A B  A-B
#2 B A  A-B
#3 B C  B-C
#4 C A  A-C
#5 A C  A-C
```

If you prefer `dplyr` this can be written as -

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% mutate(pair = paste(pmin(X, Y), pmax(X, Y), sep = '-'))
```

Comment: All solutions presented here are nice, but this is the real deal :) I've been meaning to ask when we apply `pmax` or `pmin` on a data set it is applied on every row, is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr` and `tidyr` you could try:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(pair = list(c(X, Y)),
         pair = list(sort(pair)),
         pair = list(paste(pair, collapse = "-"))) %>% 
  select(pair) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  unnest(pair)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>   pair 
#>   <chr>
#> 1 A-B  
#> 2 B-C  
#> 3 A-C
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

**data**

```
dat <- data.frame(X = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "A"), 
                  Y = c("B", "A", "C", "A", "C"))
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter, I chose @Samet response as it returns all the columns and not just the pairing. BTW, there is a comma missing after `pair = list(sort(pair))` in your code :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Have added the comma, my omission. If you want all pairs just remove the `distinct()` argument. My reading of your question was that you wanted to "avoid duplicate pairs".

Answer (score 2):

I reordered each column once

```
dat <- data.frame(X = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "A"), 
                  Y = c("B", "A", "C", "A", "C"))

library(dplyr)


dat %>%
rowwise %>%
mutate(pair = paste0(sort(c(as.character(X),as.character(Y)),decreasing = F),collapse = '-')) %>%
ungroup
```

**output;**

```
X     Y     pair 
  <fct> <fct> <chr>
1 A     B     A-B  
2 B     A     A-B  
3 B     C     B-C  
4 C     A     A-C  
5 A     C     A-C
```